# Exoplayer: How to get running Media Source

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, media-source

I have an App, that shows pictures and videos from the Internet.
Now I'm implementing a "save" function, that saves the picture/video to external or internal storage, without downloading them a second time.

For the pictures I just grab the drawable with `imageView.getDrawable()`.
 How would I achieve the same with the video thats currently buffered in the Exoplayer2.x / PlayerView? I'm not finding a `getMediaSource()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to download certain type of stream. There are subclasses for DASH, HLS, SmoothStreaming and also progressive streams. One Downloader downloads only one stream

https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/downloading-streams-6d259eec7f95